# Search and Replace string in Vim

Tags: vim, find-and-replace

I have code similar to this:

> $POST_['%']

where % is any length any letter+numbers string and I want to replace it with

```
mysql_real_escape_string($POST['%'])
```

so far I have built up this command but it doesn't recongnise $POST['.'] as any string.

```
:%s/$_POST['.']/mysql_escape_string($_POST['\=submatch(0)'])/gc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your use of `\=submatch(0)` is overly-complex, just use \0. And be aware that sub-match 0 is always the fully matched pattern, so your replacement pattern has some redundancy.  Second, the `.` atom only matches one character.  And finally, you need to escape the `[]`'s and the `$`. Try this instead:

```
:%s/\$_POST\['.\{-}'\]/mysql_escape_string(\0)/gc
```

The use of `\{-}` means to match any number of the previous atom, in a non-greedy way (as opposed to `*`).

I also note that your examples are inconsistent with each other. Is it "`$POST_[...]`", "`$_POST[...]`" or just "`$POST[...]`"?

You may want to take a look at a book like *[Mastering Regular Expressions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596528124)*.

Answer (score 2):

$, [ and ] are meta characters in regular expressions.  Try this (untested)

```
:%s/\$_POST\['.'\]/mysql_escape_string(\$_POST\['\=submatch(0)'\])/gc
```

[edit] Thanks @tink

Comment: Pattern not found: $_POST['.'\]

Comment: Actually ... $ is also a special character, so try this:  %s/\$POST_\['.'\]/mysql_escape_string($_POST\['\=submatch(0)'\])/gc

Answer (score 1):

```
s/^\(.*\)$/mysql_real_escape_string(\1)/
```

seems to do what you want. It's simple since you're just adding text around the existing string rather than actually replacing things inside it.

Comment: Im failing to rework your post to just replace $POST[''], atm it just replaces all lines with 'mysql_real_escape_string(1)'

Comment: I tried something like this: :%s/$POST['^\(.*\)$']/mysql_real_escape_string(\1)/g

Comment: Our vim's must record backref's differently, then... If nothing else, you can just replace ^ and $ in two replacement runs.

Answer (score 0):

8 months on and I need this again so I though I'd provide a neat solution:

```
sed 's/\$_GET\[\(.*\)\]/mysqli_real_escape_string(\$_GET\[\1\])/g' test.php
```